# Import modules when starting python in Windows

Tags: python, import, module

I'm using python on Windows. And I'm trying to find a way to import some default module when starting python. It means, when starting python, some modules should be already imported, just like **builtins**. Is there any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean while going into the interactive mode, just make a small startup script. Instead of just launching python with:

```
python
```

try instead:

```
python -i startupImports.py
```

startupImports.py:

```
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from customclass import myclass
#...etc
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable and point it to a python file and it will be loaded when you start python interactively without a command line script.
I have my `PYTHONSTARTUP` point to a `.pythonrc` where I try to import a `__boot__.py` (bootstrap) in the current directory for any interactive python session.

```
try:
    from __boot__ import *
except Exception:
    pass
```

There's a bunch of other things in my pythonrc like `__future__` imports, readline setup, etc.

Comment: Thanks achampion. It works!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is adding your import to `sitecustomize.py`.  This file is automatically imported at startup.  This will be loaded whether Python is started in interactive mode or not.  To quote the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> [In site.py] an attempt is made to import a module named sitecustomize, which can perform arbitrary site-specific customizations. It is typically created by a system administrator in the site-packages directory. If this import fails with an ImportError exception, it is silently ignored.

Another option is to set the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable to a startup script with your import.  This will only be executed if Python is started in interactive mode, though.

Comment: Hi Mark, the site method does not work. Is it because I'm using windows?

Comment: It works for Windows, too, and is documented: http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html.  Also see new edit above.